# Fitting 3d Image to Deep Learning Model

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am preprocessing images into a Numpy array shaped (28,28, 3). When I try and fit my data, I get the error. If I pass the whole prepped data frame, I get the error ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_20_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (360, 1)

When I pass a single value the error I get is: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_16_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 3

I've tried reprocessing the data. I have tried individually dropping in the model and training on a 1:1 and that still its not working.

## Code to preprocess

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
def read_and_prep_images(img_paths):
    z = load_img(img_paths, target_size=(28,28))
    z= img_to_array(z)
    return z
df['arrays'] = df['filepath'].apply(read_and_prep_images)
```

## model creation

```
model = Sequential()
```

## adding model layers

```
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 24, kernel_size = (5),padding = 'Same', 
              activation ='relu', input_shape = (28, 28,3)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = "softmax"))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

## Double check the shape

```
np.shape(df['arrays'].iloc[0])
```

## (28, 28, 3)

## Prepping data

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.arrays, df.label, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)
```

## Fitting Model

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=4, validation_split=0.2)
```

the model should be fit, and I can use model.predict on new images that the model has not seen before.

Answer (score 0):

*If I pass the whole prepped data frame, I get the error ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_20_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (360, 1)*

The error happens because df.arrays returns an array of arrays. So, in your case if you check `df.arrays.shape`, it would be (360,) instead of (360,28,28,3). So, you need to first remove the nesting. One way to do this is:

```
X = np.zeros((len(df.arrays), *df.arrays[0].shape))
for i in range(len(df.arrays)):
    X[i] = df.arrays[i]
```

X can now be passed to model.fit.

*When I pass a single value the error I get is: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_16_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 3)*

This is easy, just add a batch dimension. Pass df.arrays[0][None] instead of df.arrays[0].

```
>>> df.arrays[0].shape
(28, 28, 3)
>>> df.arrays[0][None].shape
(1, 28, 28, 3)
```